# How do you prove that the quadratic formula workes without doing millions of examples and proving nothing? how do you think it was created?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you prove that the quadratic formula workes without doing millions of examples and getting no actual proof in the simplest way possible?
Also how was it created?

Comment: By completing the square

Comment: Btw, regarding your title, doing millions of examples should never be part of your proof, it proves nothing ;)

Comment: The formula was derived via a proof derived by sequence of logical steps and not based on observation alone. If the proof is valid, the answer will ALWAYS be correct. This is one of the wonderful things in Mathematics. This is not true for all sciences though. The concept of proof gives the power of generalization. A huge power.

Comment: Every lottery ticket that I've ever purchased has been a loser, therefore it is impossible to win the lottery.

Answer (score 6):

$$ax^2+bx+c=0\ \mbox{ has solutions }\ x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.$$
You could simply substitute $x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ back into the original equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ and verify that it is correct.

I think more instructive is the actual derivation of the quadratic formula:
$$ax^2+bx+c=0 \iff ax^2+bx=-c \iff x^2+\frac{b}{a}x=-\frac{c}{a}$$
$$\iff x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}=-\frac{c}{a}+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}=-\frac{4ac}{4a^2}+\frac{b^2}{4a^2} \iff \left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2=\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}$$
$$x+\frac{b}{2a}=\pm\sqrt{\frac{b^2-4ac}{4a^2}}=\pm\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
So $x=-\frac{b}{2a}\pm\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.$

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) is a good place to look at the derivation.

Answer (score 0):

The essential point is to introduce **variables** (letters) for the various quantities that might appear in a quadratic equation: $a$, $b$, $c$, $x$. In this way the "millions of examples" can then be condensed into a single line
$$ax^2+bx+c=0$$
which serves as paradigm for each and everyone of these examples. The variables $a$, $b$, $c$, $x$ are "virtual" numbers, and we treat them in the derivation of the solution formula according to the laws that we are accustomed to from dealing with concrete numbers, like $4\cdot 27=(4\cdot20)+(4\cdot 7)$.

Comment: I'm confused... what do you mean?

Comment: Thanks to your comment I  have reread my answer, and I don't hesitate to confirm that it is exactly to the point of your question. Note that I didn't intend to give a proof since you have certainly seen one at the time you were first confronted with such equations.

Comment: I never was told... i learnt this outside of class...

Answer (score 0):

The trick I'm doing in solving the quadratic (and *no* I'm not memorizing that formula) is to use completion of the square. What this means is that we use the binomial theorem of the form $(u+v)^2 = u^2 + 2uv+ v^2$ to rewrite for example $x^2+px = (x+p/2)^2 - p^2/4$ (since $(x+p/2)^2 = x^2 + px + p^2/4$).

The solution of $ax^2 + bx + c$ looks as follows (if $a\ne 0$):

$$ax^2 + bx + c = 0$$
$$x^2 + {b\over a}x + {c\over a} = 0$$
$$\left(x + {b\over 2a}\right)^2-{b^2\over 4a^2} + {c\over a} = 0$$
$$\left(x + {b\over 2a}\right)^2 = {b^2\over 4a^2} - {c\over a} = {b^2 -4ac\over 4a^2}$$
$$x + {b\over 2a} = \pm \sqrt{b^2 -4ac\over 4a^2}$$
$$x = -{b\over 2a}\pm \sqrt{b^2 -4ac\over 4a^2} = {-b\pm \sqrt{b^2 -4ac}\over2a}$$

Answer (score 0):

@skyking's binomial proof works quite well, these are the steps explained:

1. $$ax^2+bx+c=0$$ (Quadratic Equation)
2. Divide both sides of the equation by a. On the right-hand side it's 0.
3. Add this to both sides of the equation. $$b^2/4a^2$$
4. Complete the square $$(x+b/2a)^2$$
5. Add $$-b^2/4a^2$$ onto both sides of the equation.
6. Add $$b^2/4a^2−c/a$$ onto both sides.
7. Take the square root of both sides.
8. Add $$-b/2a$$ to both sides and you have the quadratic formula.

Sorry for the lack of proper maths notation.